# Want to save chart.js charts to image using django cron job

Tags: django, chart.js

I want to save the chart.js canvas HTML 5 tag chart to an image, with cron/batch job with using Django. Do let me know if is there anyway, as I have searched a lot but there is not any such type of library or package I found.

The purpose of doing this to show images as a chart instead of a canvas tag, as we are facing issues while showing a chart in iPhone safari browser, due to memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to generate images from a Chart.js chart from Python.

1. Use [toBase64Image](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#tobase64image) from the Chart.js API to generate an image of your chart and send it to your server to be emailed. This solution requires a client to load every chart before it needs to be emailed (can't be done in Django only).
2. Use [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer), a Python driver for [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer), which is a headless browser.  In this case, you may load your page containing the chart and then screenshot it:

```py
browser = await launch()
page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('http://example.com/path/to/chart')
await page.screenshot({'path': 'chart.png'})
await browser.close()
```

This should work just fine but is a somewhat heavyweight solution, and requires that you render locally on the web server unless you set up some worker infrastructure.

3. Use a web service like [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/) to handle the rendering for you (note that I built this, but it's [open source](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart) and can be self-hosted).  This works by taking your Chart.js config and sending it to a web service:

```py
import json
from urllib.parse import quote

import requests

# Set up the chart.js config. This can either be a string or python dict.
chart_config = {
  'type': 'bar',
  'data': {
    'labels': ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4'],
    'datasets': [{
      'label': 'Retweets',
      'data': [12, 5, 40, 5]
    }, {
      'label': 'Likes',
      'data': [80, 42, 215, 30]
    }]
  }
}))

# Convert the python dict to a string and URL-encode it
encoded_config = quote(json.dumps(chart_config))

# Download chart
chart_url = f'https://quickchart.io/chart?c={encoded_config}'

f = requests.get(chart_url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open('/tmp/chart.png', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r:
            f.write(chunk)
```

There is also a [Python client](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart-python) that you may use.